# Unable to install Magento2 B2B module extension

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, b2b

I am installing magento2 B2B extension after creating auth.json and giving proper username and password i am getting following error.

```
composer require magento/extension-b2b 

 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.
```

and my auth.json file contain following code.

```
{
"http-basic": {
    "repo.magento.com": {
       "username": "muha********",
        "password": "Zx*********"
    }
}
```

}

anyone can help if possible

Comment: Also b2b is available on Magento Commerce only not open source

Answer (score 0):

`username` = `public key`,

`password` = `private key`

[image]

https://account.magento.com/applications/customer/login/